# Categorification of algebra structures

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, monoidal-categories

This might be a bit of a soft question.

Take a $\mathbb{C}$-linear category. Form the complex vector space spanned by its objecs modulo exact sequences. This construction is, as far as I know, the reason why $\mathbb{C}$-linear categories are thought of as categorified vector spaces.

Now put a monoidal *structure* on the category. This gives a multiplication on the vector space from before, making it into the Grothendieck algebra of the category. So monoidal structures on linear categories are categorifications of associative algebras. The *property* of the algebra being associative corresponds to *structure* of the associator on the category, as we would expect in a categorification.

As a further warmup, a commutative algebra categorifies to a braided monoidal structure. Again the *property* of commutativity is categorified to the braided *structure* in the category.

Now, imagine an involutive algebra. This is the strange bit. An involution is *structure* on the algebra. But the categorification is a *property* on the category, the existence of duals! (The dual of an object gives its involution in the algebra, and two duals to the same object are always isomorphic, so it's well-defined.)
What's going on? Why is the usual order of [stuff, structure and property](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property) reversed? Are there other examples of this phenomenon?

Remark: I'm lying a bit, the property of the involution to square to the identity categorifies to a pivotal structure, which is a monoidal natural transformation from the identity to the double dual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simpler example: in ring theory, picking a basis of your ring (as a module over the ground commutative ring $k$) is extra structure. But in category theory there is sometimes a "distinguished basis" (e.g. the simple objects in an abelian category), which will pass to just a basis after decategorifying.

For example, Hecke algebras have a [famous basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwahori%E2%80%93Hecke_algebra#Canonical_basis) called the Kazhdan-Lusztig basis which is used to define Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials, which are important in representation theory. It turns out that this basis can be thought of as coming from a categorification of Hecke algebras using what are called [Soergel bimodules](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/07/23/soergel-bimodules/).

So category theory sometimes furnishes "property-like structure" (stuff that's not preserved by functors but is uniquely determined by categorical considerations) in a way that's invisible and just looks like some random extra structure when you decategorify. This is arguably a major reason to care about categorification: to see how the category theory suggests more structure than is visible at the decategorified level.

Comment: So you're saying that some rings have a "natural" involution because they are decategorifications of monoidal categories with duals?

Comment: @Turion: yes, exactly. A typical example is fusion rings arising from decategorifications of fusion categories.